# What is the relationship between the Filesystem and the block devices?

Tags: filesystems, block-device

A filesystem is the set of methods and the data structures for keeping track of files on a disk or partition. Without it, data placed in a storage medium would be one large body of data with no way to tell where one piece of data stops and the next beings.

On the other hand, a block device is it is a device file (i.e. an interface) to another device from which data can be read from and written to.

Now, is it correct to say that a block device implements the filesystem logic for another device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, is it correct to say that a block device implements the filesystem logic for another device?

No, because the "filesystem logic" and the "block device logic" are quite different.

The "file system logic" has operations like "find file with that name", "read sequentially from that file", and below that "find the block where the 347th byte in that file is stored".

The "block device logic" has operations like "read this block" or "write this block".

That in unix the device file is actually a file in the filesystem has no relation to that, at all - it's just a trick unix uses to make the "block device logic" accessible to other applictions beside the filesystem using this block device.